# Writing 2-D array into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, arrays, google-sheets-api

I've recently faced a problem - I've got a 2D array of a changeable size, so I cannot divide it into rows or cols with hardcode.

I do write rows and cols (obviously not those from the 2D array) using ValueRange and then something like

```
service.spreadsheets().values()
            .update(SPREADSHEET_ID, "A2", nameValue)
            .setValueInputOption("RAW")
            .execute();
```

Is there any possibility to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, already found out the way to do it. If interested,

```
char ch = 'B';
    for (int i = 0; i < tasksInfo.length; i++) {
        service.spreadsheets().values()
                .update(SPREADSHEET_ID, ch + "2",
                        new ValueRange().setValues(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(tasksInfo[i]))).setMajorDimension("COLUMNS"))
                .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                .execute();
        ch++;
    }
```